# Socket server not pausing on recv(). Immediately reads 0 bytes and closes

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I have a server-client setup that works as follows:

1. The client connects to the server.
2. The client sends the server a 64-byte message telling the server how much data to read
3. The server reads that many bytes of data, responds, and the process repeats.
4. When the client is finished, it sends the server a null message
5. The server sees that the message length is 0 and closes the connection.

This seems to work fine for the first pass. After the server responds though, it doesn't wait for the client to send more data. Instead the server immediately reads 64 bytes. Since the client hasn't responded, the length of the message is 0 and the connection is closed.

I'm unsure why the server is not pausing until the client sends more data.

Here is the server loop:

```
        self.__stop = False
        while not self.__stop:
            if self.client_sock:
                # Check if the client is still connected and if data is available
                try:
                    rdy_read, rdy_write, sock_err = select.select(
                        [self.client_sock, ], [self.client_sock, ], [], 5)
                except select.error as err:
                    self.stop()
                    return

                if len(rdy_read) > 0:
                    # msg length will be sent as bytes
                    read_data = self.client_sock.recv(64)

                    # Check if the socket has been closed
                    if read_data == 0:
                        self.stop()
                    else:
                        msg_length = int(read_data)
                        msg = self.client_sock.recv(msg_length)

                        response = f"{[12, 15, 66]}\n"

                        msg_size = padded_size_of_msg(response)
                        self.client_sock.send(msg_size)
                        self.client_sock.send(f"{response}".encode('utf-8'))

            else:
                print(
                    f"[THREAD {self.number}] No client connected.")
                self.stop()
        self.close()
```

The function padded_size_of_msg() is to calculate the length of the message, pad that number to be 64-bytes, then send that to the client:

```
def padded_size_of_msg(msg):
    msg_length = len(msg)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode('utf-8')
    send_length += b' ' * (64- len(send_length))
    return send_length
```

The complete class declaration is below:

```
class ServerSocketThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_sock, client_addr, number):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client_sock = client_sock
        self.client_addr = client_addr
        self.number = number

    def run(self):

        self.__stop = False
        while not self.__stop:
            if self.client_sock:
                # Check if the client is still connected and if data is available
                try:
                    rdy_read, rdy_write, sock_err = select.select(
                        [self.client_sock, ], [self.client_sock, ], [], 5)
                except select.error as err:
                    print(
                        f"[THREAD {self.number}] Select() failed on socket with {self.client_addr}")
                    self.stop()
                    return

                if len(rdy_read) > 0:
                    # msg length will be sent as bytes
                    read_data = self.client_sock.recv(64)

                    # Check if the socket has been closed
                    if read_data == 0:
                        print(
                            f"[THREAD {self.number}] {self.client_addr} closed the socket")
                        self.stop()
                    else:
                        msg_length = int(read_data)
                        # Client will send msg as bytes. No need to decode to str
                        msg = self.client_sock.recv(msg_length)

                        response = f"{[12, 15, 66]}\n"

                        # Send outputs to client as bytes
                        msg_size = padded_size_of_msg(response)
                        self.client_sock.send(msg_size)
                        self.client_sock.send(f"{response}".encode('utf-8'))

            else:
                print(
                    f"[THREAD {self.number}] No client connected.")
                self.stop()
        self.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop = True

    def close(self):
        if self.client_sock:
            print(
                f"[THREAD {self.number}] Closing conn with {self.client_addr}")
            self.client_sock.close()
```

Comment: create minimal working code for server and client. Do you use `socket.setblocking(0)` ?

Comment: The client has closed the connection without sending anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with using nc from the command line.

If I were to try and send "test" from the client, it would register the size as 4-bytes and tell the server to read 4-bytes. From the terminal, nc would instead send "test\n". The newline character '\n' would not be read and instead waited in the queue. When the second recv() was called, it immediately read the '\n' and took that as an indication to close the connection.